# Circle styles in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I'm working with some Mapbox GL JS code that creates a blue dot, and I'm working if I can tweak it to paint a black ring with a transparent centre instead (Kind of like an "O")?

My code below is:

```
 paint: {
        'circle-radius': 14,
        'circle-color': '#004cf0',
        }
```

If someone could point me in the right direction it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```js
paint: {
        'circle-radius': 14,
        'circle-color': 'transparent',
        'circle-stroke-color': 'black',
        'circle-stroke-width': 2,
        }
```